# SQLite 'string was not recognized as valid DateTime'

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, datetime

I am attempted to retrieve DateTime information from each of my rows in my SQLite database, but I am receiving the error 'string was not recognized as valid DateTime' and I don't have much idea why this is happening so any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    string gameName = row["GameName"].ToString();
    //DateTime releaseTime = (DateTime)row["ReleaseTime"];
    DateTime releaseTimeGB = DateTime.ParseExact("dd/mm/yyyy", row["ReleaseTime"].ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
    gameInfo.Add(new GameInfo() { Name = gameName, ReleaseTime = releaseTimeGB});
}
```

Now the commented out section in the above code does work but it retrieves the DateTime information in a format that I don't want, so the error is coming from the `ParseExact()` method. After looking around online it's pretty apparent that the exact source of the error is from calling the `ToString()` method on `row["ReleaseTime"]`, but I am unsure on how to correct this as this is my first time using SQLite.

Comment: What is the value and type of `row["ReleaseTime"]`?

Comment: @DavidG It should be DateTime as that's what I specified when executing the SQL to create the row, the value is something like '2015-09-01 00:00:00' for each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `row["ReleaseTime"]` is already a `DateTime` object so you don't need to convert it to a string with `ToString` then convert it back to `DateTime` again. Instead cast it directly to `DateTime`:

```
DateTime releaseTimeGB = (DateTime)row["ReleaseTime"];
```

Or even better, use the [Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) extension for `DataRow`:

```
DateTime releaseTimeGB = row.Field<DateTime>("ReleaseTime");
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I originally did, but the problem is I want it to be set to the British date format which is dd/mm/yyyy which is why I was using .ParseExact() to do that, but using .ParseExact() means that I needed to convert row["ReleaseTime"] to a string which is were the error is occuring

Comment: @CallumHoughton - you have it backwards. `DateTime` instance does not care/know about in what format it will be displayed. Only when it is time to put it on screen, should you specify the format.

Comment: @Igor oh okay, so how would I convert it into the GB format?

Comment: @CallumHoughton - `releaseTimeGB.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")` - when you need the string to show the user.

Comment: @CallumHoughton The display format should always be done in your UI layer, not your database or business logic. As Igor suggests, the DateTime object has no knowledge about display format, nor should it. Always keep data in the format it was intended to be in for as long as possible.

Comment: @DavidG Ah okay, I'll keep that in mind I'll store my displayed date in a completely different variable then than the variable containing the date data.

Comment: @Igor That worked thank you!, If you submit that as an answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer if you want?

Comment: Sorry to harp on about this but you shouldn't convert it to a string only to convert it back to a date. @Igor was only giving you a solution on how to display to the user, not how you should change this code.

Comment: @DavidG you don't need to apologize I'm only a hobbyist programmer so any advice on how to layout and organize my code is well needed haha. Would storing two different variants of the data, one as a string to be displayed in the UI and one as a DateTime variable which I'd use later on for other things, be okay or would it be bad practice?

Comment: @CallumHoughton No problem! It's impossible for me to tell exactly how your user interface is, but chances are that you don't need to store the date anywhere else at all. Use the ToString("....") method as Igor suggested to put the data into a textbox/label/whatever, but no need to have a different variable.

Comment: @CallumHoughton Or even better use some of the other methods such as `ToShortDateString` or `ToLongDateString` and let the local culture of the user determine how the date is formatted.

Comment: @DavidG Thank you for the advice! I'll go back to editing my code then and implement the suggestions :)

Comment: @CallumHoughton You're welcome, and keep up the good work in improving yourself. There's always room to get better :)

Comment: Curious why this answer was suddenly worthy of a downvote?

Answer (score -1):

If you convert it into ToString then it takes culture specific format.
So if you again want to convert that string to DateTime you have to Use that culture specific format.
And I think for EN-GB format is not dd/mm/yyyy. It's mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Nah for GB it should be dd/mm/yyyy, but then even replacing 'new CultureInfo("en-GB")' with 'CultureInfo.CurrentCulture' still returns the same error.

Comment: if you wanna store value as a string then siply use 
string date = DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Comment: Try like this
DateTime.ParseExact("dd/mm/yyyy", row["ReleaseTime"].ToString(dd/mm/yyyy), new CultureInfo("en-GB"));